# Пересборка webpack при добавлении .html файла в runtime

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack4

Добрых времени суток, проблема, есть webpack config, всё работает как нужно, за исключением одного но, когда в рантайме (при зпущенном локальном сервере) создаешь новый `.html` файл, то при попытке пройти по адресу: localhost.../*.html, выдаёт:

> cannot get /*.html

где * - имя файла

сборка:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
};

const PAGES_DIR = `${PATHS.src}/html`;
const PAGES = fs.readdirSync(PAGES_DIR).filter(file => file.endsWith('.html'));

module.exports = {
    externals: {
        paths: PATHS
    },
    entry: {
        bundle: `${PATHS.src}/js/Application`
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|mp4)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~': PATHS.src
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: `${PATHS.src}/assets`,
            to: `${PATHS.dist}/assets`
        }]),
        ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
            filename: `${PATHS.dist}/${page}`,
            inject: true, // enable/disable auto-inject js/css files into HTML code
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true, // optional
                removeComments: true // optional
            }
        }))
    ]
};
```

понимаю, что переменная `PAGES` не обновляется, но как можно сделать так, чтобы обновлялась?